# Can't attach jdb to maven test debug session

Tags: java, maven, junit, jdb

I'm debugging a test using maven:

```
mvnDebug test
```

Maven says the debug server is running at port 8000, so I try to attach a jdb debug session to it:

```
jdb -sourcepath ./src/main/java/:./src/test/java/ -attach 8000
```

A number of problems arise here.

1. I cannot view any of my source files, even after setting breakpoints and running.
2. When the test runs, it seems to completely ignore any breakpoints I set, as if jdb couldn't find the class I was referring to.

Any ideas why this could be? I can also debug my project in eclipse, I just cannot attach jdb to my project.